# ReactJS rewrite function not trigger

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-rewriting

I'm trying to workaround for the NestJS CORS issue. I found rewrite is the best option and testing it. I followed this documentation [enter link description here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) .

But it seems like not trigger the new rewrite function. because it call the local route when I call the API URL.

[image]

This is my **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/api-server/:path*",
                destination: "https://localhost:44369/api/:path*",
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

This is my API call function

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    const form = e.target;
    setServerState({ submitting: true });
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api-server/airdrop/airdrop-submission",
        data,
        origin: "*",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
        .then((_res) => {
            handleServerResponse(true, "Thanks! for joining with us", form);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err.response != null) {
                handleServerResponse(false, err.response.data.error, form);
            } else {
                handleServerResponse(false, err.message, form);
            }
        });
};
```

I have .net core API running while I'm testing this.
[image]

Comment: Rewrite is doing as expected. It is mapping your server API to localhost as you have configured, the error you are getting is because there is no server running in localhost. hence, the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

[CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) is a browser feature not a language feature, you can't fix it from client side, you need to allow your domain in API server or run a local version of your server code and rewrite request to local server using NextJS [rewrite](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Rewrite is doing as expected. It is mapping your server API to localhost as you have configured,

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/api-server/:path*",
                destination: "https://localhost:44369/api/:path*",
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

the error you are getting is because there is no server running in localhost. hence, the 404 error.

Run api server locally and enable CORS for your testing.

Comment: Actually, my API is running locally.